# problem with calling external "gdrive" command line tools

Tags: external-calls

I am on linux.

There is command line tool called "gdrive" that can handle google drive upload and download. It's github address is https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive . But I got problem calling this program inside mathematica.

As the [gdrive tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-access-google-drive-from-linux-gdrive/) say, a first run of gdrive, you will meet this prompt

[image]

after verification, you don't need to verify it anymore, and in terminal

```
gdrive list
```

will show files on my google drive

> admin@Precision:~/wc/gdrive$ ./gdrive list
>
> Id                                  Name
>   Type   Size      Created 1nyfgXauEC6JX1qeAMGtO85e_tIepx_Fg
>   39d465076ed1bdeaf4f...aab359f92a7c1c4.gz   bin    12.8 MB   2018-11-07
>   14:53:53

Then I tried inside mathematica

```
SetDirectory["/home/admin/wc/gdrive"];
RunProcess[{"./gdrive", "list"}, "StandardOutput"]
```

it outputs

> Failed to list files: Get \
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?alt=json&fields=\
>   nextPageToken%2Cfiles%28id%2Cname%2Cmd5Checksum%2CmimeType%2Csize%\
>   2CcreatedTime%2Cparents%29&orderBy=&pageSize=30&q=trashed+%3D+false+\
>   and+%27me%27+in+owners: read tcp \
>   172.16.24.201:35444->216.58.200.42:443: read: connection reset by peer

It just like the "gdrive" is not verified and being used for the first time!!! How to solve this issue?

---

PS.
at the same time, python has no problem calling external gdrive

[image]

Comment: I have never used `gdrive` before, but I just installed it using the homebrew invocation from the Github page, and what you described immediately worked for me from within Mathematica with: `RunProcess[{"gdrive", "list"}, ProcessDirectory -> "/usr/local/bin/"]` (on macOS with M11.3)

Comment: In short, try pointing `ProcessDirectory` to the output of `which gdrive`

Comment: @user6014 hi, thank you for help. Did you connect to your google drive? What did got after running RunProcess. The github doesn't show a way of apt install. So I just download the executable directly

Comment: Yes I connected to my Google Drive. Running `RunProcess[{"gdrive", "list"}, ProcessDirectory -> "/usr/local/bin/"]` listed the entirety of my Google Drive file directory.

Comment: @user6014 Thank you so much. Do you have spare time to try to use the compiled executable listed in download section instead of homebrew version? I somehow feel there is some difference.